# text align left and right around centre of div

Tags: html, css

imagine the star * is centred inside the div

```
                           textAlignRight * text AlignLeft
```

That's basically what I am trying to achieve

```html
<center>
  <span class="left_host">Right aligned</span>
  *
  <span class="right_host">Left aligned</span>
</center>
```

Any help to get this solved would be awesome

thank you

Comment: I am imagining a star now. However, what is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: You really need to provide more context. And the usual: What have you tried so far? Show us the code.

Comment: 2 divs: alightRight div with text aligned to the right and align Left div with text aligned to the left?

Comment: @CodeWhisperer - Don't forget to imagine the star! :)

Comment: lol. when i text alight left/right it always starts from the edge of the div .. not the centre

Comment: @LcSalazar Yeah I definitely imagined a star first time i read this :)

Comment: how do i post my code?

Comment: @MarkPerry you are using 1 div I am saying use 2 divs one for each group of text.

Comment: @MarkPerry - Edit you question and post the code with a 4-space indent...

Comment: ok - that makes sense, let me try now ...thank you

Comment: @MarkPerry There is plenty of good advice regarding how to create good quality questions under 'help', top right corner

Comment: @MarkPerry You actually put a star in the HTML ? :D

Comment: Despite the fact that you are using a deprecated element `<center>` (where you should be centering with css), the provided code gives the output as you posted in the question, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just went away and tried the multiple div technique as well and it worked .. though a little more clunky than the replies I have received. thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it structurally:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.left {
  text-align: right;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
}
.right {
  text-align: left;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 200px;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 580px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">This text will be aligned right but appear on the left of stuff that you want to put in the center of all this madness.</div>
  <div class="center">* This will be centered. *</div>
  <div class="right">This text will be aligned left but appear on the right of stuff that you want to put in the center of all this madness.</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zn2uafm3/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="right">text aligned to the right</div>
    <div class="star">&#9733;</div> 
    <div class="left">text aligned to the left</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eee;
}

.wrap > div
{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.right
{
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}

.left
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

i've added buttons to the live example to let you see what happen when more content will append dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/wqsb38jr/1/